# Bash script to SSH into server

Tags: bash, ssh

I am developing a script to SSH into a number of servers. But all the servers have wheel user enabled. So the environment changes when I run the script in my local machine i.e I SSH as wheel user and then I need to switch to root and all that in one script. Please help.

Comment: please make it clearer...What exactly you want and what you tried so far ?

Comment: I answered your question...hope to be helpful

Comment: MortezaLSC - I have many servers to access and all of them have wheel user enabled so I can't create a script to directly login as root.

Comment: I wrote script for you..If this is what you want you should tick for accepting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT='
sudo -kSs <<EOF
RootPassword
#Do stuff here
EOF
'

while read pass ip; do
    sshpass -p$pass ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' -p <port> wheel@$ip "$Script"
done <<HERE
pass1 ip1
pass2 ip2
pass3 ip3
  .    .
  .    .
  .    .
HERE
```

Comment: Ideally, you want passwordless (private key/public key) access to each server, and then as a member of `wheel` on each, you should configure `pam/sudoers` to allow you to `su/sudo` as required within your script. You do not want to place the `RootPassword` in a shell script -- ever.